# show pop up only first time user login (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple question about a project I working on it
I need to show a Modal Popup once ***when the user login in first time no more only once!!!***
I create this code but it still not working

**test.blade.php**

```
@if ($first_time_login)
   <h3>Welcome Popup</h3>
@else 
  <h3>Hey!  Nothing to Show</h3>
@endif
```

**TestController**

```
public function Test()
{

    if (Auth::user()->first_time_login) {
        $first_time_login = true;
        Auth::user()->first_time_login = 1;
        Auth::user()->save();
    } else {
        $first_time_login = false;
    }

    return view(
        'test', 
        ['first_time_login' => $first_time_login]
    ); 
}
```

**2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php**

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('first_time_login')->default(false);
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few things on your code.

Firstly you are declaring the `first_time_login` field as a string, it should be boolean with default value of `true`. Like this:

**2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php**

```php
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->boolean('first_time_login')->default(true);
    });
```

Another thing, after checking if it's a first time login you are setting it to `1`. This will make your field remain as `true`. Change it to:

**TestController**

```php
public function Test()
{

    if (Auth::user()->first_time_login) {
        $first_time_login = true;
        Auth::user()->first_time_login = false;
        Auth::user()->save();
    } else {
        $first_time_login = false;
    }

    return view(
        'test', 
        ['first_time_login' => $first_time_login]
    ); 
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What goes wrong? The message is shown? The user record is being updated?

Comment: can you rewrite the whole code source please I dont now where is the problem

Comment: I updated my answer with the full code. I also forgot to mention that the default value for `first_time_login` should be true.